# Gradle подключает неопределенный модуль

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle

Не могу понять, как подключается модуль. Подскажите, пожалуйста)

В зависимостях build.gradle такого модуля нет и сами классы из этого модуля я не могу импортировать(то есть подключить для использования).

Поэтому возникает ошибка  **error: cannot find symbol**

Но, если зайти в директорию

C:\Users\ivan.vovk.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.threeten

там этот модуль есть. Удаляю его, запускаю синхронизацию, он опять каким-то образом там появляется.

Если подключаю **implementation 'org.threeten:threetenbp:1.3.8'** его правильно,

то получаю ошибку **java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class org.threeten.bp**

Invalidate cache and restart не помогает

P.S. это после обновления студии появилось, возможно что связано с этим.

Comment: Очень похоже, что какая-то зависимость  использует другую версию этой библиотеки

Comment: @woesss, да похоже на то, а как можно определить?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#view-dependency-tree - посмотрите дерево зависимостей, оно покажет кто что за собой тянет .